# How to display a table of destinations based on prices

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have a "destinations" table with the following html.

```
<table align = "center" class="table table-bordered" style = "border-radius: 15px;">

        <tr>
           <th>Destination</th>
           <th>Description</th>
           <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>Villa Jibacoa <br><img style= "height:150px; width:170px; float:left;"src = "images/Villa.jpg"/></td>
           <td>
            <ul>

              <li>255 rooms</li>
              <li>One 9-storey building</li>
              <li>4 restaurants</li>
              <li>5 bars</li>
              <li>Pool</li>
              <li>110 and 220 volts (adaptor required)</li>
            </ul>

            </td>
           <td>$784 <div style="position: relative; margin-top: 40px;"><button  id = "first" type="button" onclick = "SeatAssignment(1)" class="btn btn-success">Book Now!</button></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>Gran Caribe Puntarena <br><img style= "height:150px; width:170px; float:left;"src = "images/grandcarib.jpg"/></td>
           <td> 
              <ul>

              <li>110 rooms</li>
              <li>Bungalow-style villas</li>
              <li>2 restaurants</li>
              <li>2 bars</li>
              <li>Pools</li>
              <li>220 volts (adaptor required)</li>
            </ul>
           </td>
           <td> $947 <div style="position: relative; margin-top: 40px;"><button  type="button" onclick = "SeatAssignment(2)" class="btn btn-success">Book Now!</button></div></td>
        </tr>
```

in another html file I have a calculator form. I have it so that based on the price that the user enters it will return a trips that are within their price range. Here is the form:

```
<form onSubmit="return MoneyForTrip();">
<h1> Enter the amount of money you would like to spend on your next trip. </h1><br>

        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
          <input type="text" id= "moneyfortrip" class="form-control">

        </div>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Show My Trips</button>

        </form>
```

And the Javascript function that it passes upon submit:

```
function MoneyForTrip()
{


var money = parseInt(document.getElementById('moneyfortrip').value);

if (money <= 800)
{

}

else if (money > 800 && money <=1200)
{

}

else if (money > 1200 && money <=2000)
{

}
else if (money > 2000)
{

}

else
{

}
return false;

}
```

Not sure what to put in the if and else if statements. I would like so that it depending on which bracket the input from the user falls into it will display a trip within that price range. I would like for a table to list appropriate trips on the same page as my calculator form page.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Is data for trips stored somewhere and output dynamically on server or in page by javscript? Would help to add some things to html right when it gets created

Comment: not quite sure what you mean. I am not using a server at all, solely javascript.

Comment: ok..so source of trips is just hard coded in the html?

Comment: yes all the information is just inside my destinations.html file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common pattern is to apply attributes to the elements to categorize them and then use the attributes to conditionally hide or display the elements you want.

Here is a sample JS Fiddle to displaying rows conditionally. NOTE: I used jQuery as document.getElementByClassName is still not fully supported across browsers:

http://jsfiddle.net/eqkmv/1/

Here is an enhanced javascript method. It will hide all elements which have a class named 'trip-result'. Then it will show the elements which match the if statements.

```
function MoneyForTrip() {
    var money = parseInt(document.getElementById('moneyfortrip').value);

    $('.trip-result').hide();

    if (money <= 800) {
        $('.trip-less-800').show();
    }

    if (money > 800 && money <= 1200) {
        $('.trip-800-1200').show();
    }
}
```

Here is the important update to the html. Noticed it has two classes. One to identify it when we match the conditional. And one to identify it when we want to hide it. Also, it starts out as invisible.

```
<tr class="trip-less-800 trip-result" style="display:none">
```

Answer (score 0):

There is many ways. You could for example assign a class to the different table rows in the different price range, and then with the JavaScript you make them visible or invisible as needed.

Comment: So would I just have the whole table set to invisible on the calculator form page and then just make the information visible as needed? How would I go about making it visible and invisible?

Comment: Try document.getElementByClassName("mediumcost").style.display = "block"; (to show specific table rows. The rest you can hide with) document.getElementByClassName.style.display = "none";  -  edit: of course you have to assign classes to the different rows for that :)

Comment: so in this case will the whole table need to be invisible on the calculator form page and then only made visible as it corresponds to the right price range? I would rather have it retrieve information from the table that is already created in destinations and then display the correct information as needed on the calculator form page is possible.